# How to remove noise using morphological filtering

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, image-preprocessing, noise

I have two groups of dots that both contain noise between them:

[image]

The line that separates the two groups in the picture is diagonal in shape.
I tried to use morphological filtering on this image to remove the noise between these two groups but failed.

This is the code that I tried to run on this image:

```
from skimage.morphology import opening, square

new_image = opening(image, square(3))
```

It did remove a little bit of noise, but not enough for them to become two distinct groups.

I am using DBSCAN on the `new_image` and DBSCAN still treats them as one group.

I would like to know whether I am giving the correct argument to the function opening. Or maybe there is some other way (better way) to remove the noise between the two groups?

Comment: DBSCAN definitely can do this with the right parameters, but dinner of the points on the right will be noise. But for a single image you don't need such automatization at all - how many such images do you have?

Comment: I have 6400 images

Comment: can you tell me what parameters dbscan should be provided to separate it to two groups?

Comment: Well, there will always be the split of group in the bottom left, too. There are many parameter settings that are good. I'd try radius 3 and minpts 10 for example, but why don't you just try some values - this is 2d pixels, you can find good values just by counting or ticking boxes in paper. Then show so!e difficult images along with the best results you got.

Comment: dbscan do not contains parameters as radius or minpts, it contains eps, min_samples, metric etc'

Comment: Sklearn uses non-standard names. The original DBSCAN called the parameter minPts if I am not mistaken. But if you read the documentation (you should *always* understand the options you are using, don't treat algorithms as black boxes) it should be obvious how they align.

Comment: As for the metric, I would also consider L1, but then clearly you need to adjust the other parameters.

Comment: Since you are looking for connectiveness of the clusters, spectral clustering might work better.